# xrandr script for external monitor adjustment not executing from udev

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, xrandr, udev, schedule

My laptop has a 4k screen and I also have an external 1080p monitor. The scaling is incorrect on the monitor and so every time I plug in the monitor, I execute an xrandr command to fix it. I figured I could automate the process and have created a udev rule to execute when it recognizes my monitor is plugged into the HDMI port. The issue is that the xrandr scripts are not being executed. I put an echo to a text file in the script right above the xrandr command to make sure it was reaching that point and it was. I have also tried using sleep commands, but the external monitor just waits for the script to finish sleeping before turning on. Running the script manually works.

My udev rule file is as follows:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/ext_monitor_scale"
```

xrandr script:

```
#!/bin/sh
USER_NAME=`who | grep "(:0)" | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
HDMI_STATUS=`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/card0-DP-3/status`

if [ $HDMI_STATUS = "connected" ]
then
        echo "test" >> test.txt
        sudo -u $USER_NAME xrandr --output DP-3 --scale 2x2 --output eDP-1 --scale 0.9999x0.9999
fi
```

Does anyone know a workaround? It seems I need to wait and allow the monitor to come on incorrectly and then have the script execute the xrandr command, but since the display waits for sleep before it auto adjusts I don't know how to go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking for a solution, but your script helped me to get it right.

The problem is that you think it is necessary to run it as the user that is logged in at the moment. First of all, this isn't necessary, and second of all, the way you do it is wrong, because the call to 'who' will reply with root as the script is executed as root.

To solve your problem, remove the sudo and add the correct display identifier:

```
#!/bin/sh
HDMI_STATUS=`cat /sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-1/status`

if [ $HDMI_STATUS = "connected" ]
then
    DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xrandr ...
else
    DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xrandr ...
fi
```

This works perfectly for me.

As a bonus, you can replace your call to xrandr with a call to an arandr-script (arandr can save its configuration as a script in ~/.screenlayout (or anywhere you want). By using those scripts, you only need to update them to make it work automatically on the udev event.